# can the raspberry pi 2 automaticly setup crossover ethernet connections?

Tags: raspbian, networking

can the raspberry pi 2 automatically setup crossover Ethernet connections?
I have a webserver with a networked web camera. The camera is behind a router, and the server is on the raspberry pi. I would like to move the camera into my car, and directly attach the camera to the raspberry pi via an Ethernet cable.
But I only have patch cables on hand. Cant the raspberry pi handle that type of connection, and set it up to cross over, and work properly, automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Although the Pi is capable of utilizing any cable as a cross over cable and will automatically detect this. The Pi is not capillary of assigning itself an IP address so unless your camera has a built in DNS server,which is highly unlikely. You are going to have to first set up a static ip address for the Pi using a monitor and keyboard. Or by connecting the Pi to the A working internet connection then setting up your static ip to be initialized on the next boot.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer for setting things up is totally fine.

I just want to add that you don't need a crossover ethernet cable for that, as the raspberry pi and probably most of the recent computers NIC's support Auto-MDIX. So you can just use a normal ethernet cable as long as the other device also supports it.

after setting an ip adress on your pi and your device they should be able to communicate with each other.